# Absolute positioning error in IE6 with dropdown list

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-6, css-position

I have a div, that I'm using JavaScript to position, so that when someone hovers over an image, it displays a tooltip message that follows along with the pointer.  (Using tooltip-0.2.js )

The problem is that when a user goes to the page in IE6, a disabled dropdown box on the page is showing through this absolutely positioned tooltip when it tries to hover over it.  How can I get this dropdownlist to know its proper place?  ;)

Comment: Its hard to find people still using IE6...congrats.

Comment: Sadly, the last time our company looked at our usage logs, about 25-30% of the people visiting our site use IE6.  When we work on sites, we still have to cater to these backwards souls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put an iframe element behind your layer to block such things from showing through.  It will also block Flash objects from showing through.  It's messy, but works.

Answer (score 0):

You better use another tooltip lib.

The "shining-through" effect is well known and other tooltips work around it.

I can't name a specific other tooltip lib.

Comment: Sadly, this is not an option--it would require stripping this lib from several other places in our website, and we're not ready to take such a step at this time.